# C++ function vs template with an integer parameter?

Tags: c++, function, templates

Reading the Wikibook [Optimizing C++](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Optimizing_C%2B%2B), in [this paragraph](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Optimizing_C%2B%2B/Code_optimization/Instruction_count#Template_integer_parameters) there is the following suggestion:

> If an integer value is a constant in the application code, but is a variable in library code, make it a template parameter.

So if I have a function like

```
void myfunction(int param)
{
     switch(param)
     {
          case 1:
              do_something_1();
          break;

          case 2:
              do_something_2();
          break; 

          ...

          case 100:                 // 100 is taken as example
              do_something_100();
          break;
     }
}
```

Is convenient to replace it with the following?

```
template<int param> void myfunction()
{
     switch(param)
     {
          case 1:
              do_something_1();
          break;

          case 2:
              do_something_2();
          break; 

          ...

          case 100:                 // 100 is taken as example
              do_something_100();
          break;
     }
}
```

Or is completely unnecessary? Could you please explain to me the reason?

Comment: If the compiler knows the value of "param" at compile-time, it may completely remove the switch to keep the only code that can be reached.

Comment: Not very useful. If it *is*  a constant, and you let the compiler inline the code, I guess the result will be the same.

Comment: Reasons are already given on that page you have mentioned.              If an integer value is a constant in the application code, but is a variable in library code, make it a template parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tweak you have in mind only works if the parameter is known at compile time. In your quote, there is an assumption about the application code which you can't make when writing a library.

If your function calls in the application code used to be

```
const int x = 3;
myfunction(1);
myfunction(2);
myfunction(x);
//etc...
```

They can be rewritten as follows.

```
const int x = 3;
myfunction<1>();
myfunction<2>();
myfunction<x>();
//etc...
```

But if `x` is a variable, it's not possible:

```
int x = ...;      // unknown at compile-time!
myfunction<x>();  // will fail to compile!
```

As stated above, there are cases where you shouldn't make assumptions about the application when writing a library. Sometimes you want or need to do. Let's consider the case where you *expect* the application to use a constant, but you don't want to *force* it to do so.

You want to **optimize** for the case it will use a **constant**, but **still allow** the use of a **variable**. For this, I suggest two options:

- Make two alternatives, one with a template parameter and one with a function parameter.
- **Inline** the function, so when compiling the application code the function's definition is seen by the compiler and can be used to optimize it to a single `do_something_*()` call *if* the parameter was constant.

Note that both options require exposing the function's definition to the application's code. I'd prefer to use the second option.

Comment: Both a template and an inlined function needs to expose function definition (unless you dare entering the dungeons of now-deprecated and never-really-supported C++03 exported template)

Comment: That's what I said in my last sentence (note the "also"). I'll rewrite it a bit.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you'd want to use `myfunction`. For example, your templated function could not be used with a variable declared at runtime:

```
int dosomethingmaybe = 1;
dosomethingmaybe += 2;
myfunction< dosomethingmaybe >(); // <--- Error, you cannot instantiate a template with a non-constant variable
myfunction( dosomethingmaybe ); // <--- Will call `do_something_3();`, according to your code
```

You use templates when you can provide an argument **at compile-time** that won't be changed at run-time. Templates are always evaluated at compile-time, and thus their ***inputs and outputs are fixed before the program is ever run***!

Make a template version if you know that someone can fix the input and expect a certain output of functionality ahead of time. Otherwise, the regular function runtime version is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you would actually see a performance advantage in real situations here. If the call is inlined, there is no difference between the two approaches - as long as the parameter is known at compile time (which it must be), a decent compiler will remove the unnecessary switch in both cases. The only case where you would see a difference is if inlining does not occur - in this case the templated approach would allow the switch to be removed, while the other would not. However, the function call overhead is likely to dwarf the cost of the switch in this case anyway.